# Trigger the update of a TableView's CellValue without changing the value

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview

Each row contains three cells with RGB values. I use these RGB values to set the background of another cell in the same row. On the cells that need to have the background colored I have a callback that picks up the RGB values and sets the background perfectly. So the whole `TableView` looks exactly as I needed. I have a color picker and this picker needs to update the selected row containing the three RGB values. I'm able to set the new three RGB values but I also need the cell with the colored background to updated itself to the new RGB values. In the code below I have found a way to do this but I believe this is rather ugly.

```
@FXML void handleColorPicker(ActionEvent event) 
{
    int r = (int) (comColorPicker.getValue().getRed()*255);
    int g = (int) (comColorPicker.getValue().getGreen()*255);
    int b = (int) (comColorPicker.getValue().getBlue()*255);

    ComTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setRCom(r);
    ComTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setGCom(g);
    ComTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setBCom(b);
    // we need to kick the cell value so it updates also the background color so we clear and rewrite the text string
    String currentName = ComTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getCommodityName();
    ComTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setCommodityName(" ");
    ComTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setCommodityName(currentName);
}
```

The above code's last three lines trigger the cell's `updateItem` but I think I'm doing this in an ugly way. I'm wondering, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Use JavaFX [property value extractors](http://www.jensd.de/wordpress/?p=1650)
2. Partially rewrite your data class

---

If you are going down route 2:
Lets assume your data class in the table is ColorData` and has the three attributes:

- `int RCom`
- `int GCom`
- `int BCom`
- `String CommodityName`

Now if you change your `CommodityName` from `String` to `StringProperty` and provide this to the `TableView` via

```
commodityNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().commodityNameProperty());
```

Where `commodityNameColumn` is the TableColumn of your TableView displaying the `commodityNameProperty()` a new method of `ColorData` giving access to the new StringProperty.

Now if you change the StringProperty via its setter, and the value actually changes, the TableCell will update accordingly.

---

If there is still something unclear how to link a data class to the JavaFX TableView I recommend [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part2/).